# Google places autocomplete don't work in my emulator or VMware

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I have exactly the same problem as
[Autocomplete textview google places api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581175/autocomplete-textview-google-places-api)

But the fixes suggested to him don't fix the problem with my case.
I uses the exact same code. But it does not work.

tanks for the api tip

i debuged the problem and saw i am getting a respond of zero_results

Any suggestion?

```
                String input = "";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url =         "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="
                + output + "?" + parameters;
```

Comment: you are getting you own API key from https://code.google.com/apis/console??

Comment: yes i have got an api key- i have kept on tring to debug it.. apperently i get from the server this answer: 
**{   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",   "predictions" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}**
 i have gave google my SHA1 certificate and the packet name of the activity who call him
any segestion whay it will heppend?

Comment: ok fixt the api key... replaced it with server api key
not i get a response of: ZERO_RESULTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is you API key configuration. Make sure you are creating an API key in "Public API access" section.

[image: Public API access]

- You can find how to get the finger print in this post:

[How to obtain Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for OAuth 2.0 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android)

- Then in [google console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) register you API key. Remember add to the final you name package declared in your Android Manifest.
- finger print example:

F7:DB:FF:EB:6E:AD:C1:D6:84:05:1D:BA:F7:94:0D:E4:1F:2E:3C:8C;cl.hcarrasco.tm

- Enable Google Places API:
  Remember too do this:

[image]

I hope this can help you.